# Cookie reading value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am using VS2015, C#.

My cookie value is:

> Provider=Custom&Email=someemail@gmail.com&UserName=John&FirstName=Test&LastName=LastTest&Expires=11.7.2016
>   11:03:05

I am trying to get this value with:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
HttpCookie cookie = context.Request.Cookies["Login"];

string provider = cookie["Provider"];
string email = cookie["Email"];
```

both provider and email are null. How can I get values from cookie?

**EDIT**

Cookie is saved with:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
                cookie["Provider"] = "Custom";
                cookie["Email"] = "test@gmail.com"; 
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

**SECOND EDIT**

I think the problem is encryption. I am using my own encrpytion mechanism. Cookie.value looks fine after decryption, but Cookie.Values is a little bit different than original. I think that's the problem.

```
Cookie.Value (before encryption): Provider=Custom&Email=test@gmail.com
Cookie.Value (after decryption):      Provider=Custom&Email=test@gmail.com

Cookie.Values (before encryption) :{Provider=Custom&Email=test%40gmail.com}
Cookie.Value (after decryption - is different):       {Provider%3dCustom%26Email%3dtest%40gmail.com}
```

Comment: What is the raw value of `cookie.Value`?

Comment: raw value? It's just like it's written above, in yellow. Copy - paste from visual studio: Provider=Custom&Email=franjo.brekalo@gmail.com&UserName=FranjoB&FirstName=Franjo&LastName=Brekalo&Expires=11.7.2016 11:03:05

Comment: Try using `cookie.Values`

Comment: I've tried that also. I see cookie.Values - values are here. But when I try cookie.Values["Provider"], it's empty.

Comment: Did you assign a value to cookie's expires property like cookie.Expires=DateTime.Now.AddDay(1)

Comment: Yes, I did. I will post what I think is a problem.

Comment: I think the problem is you make cookie namee "Login" but you try to get Provider and Email cookies.Instead make two different cookies and add them to response and try to get again.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
HttpCookie cookie1 = Request.Cookies["Login"];

if (cookie1 != null)
{
    string provider = cookie1["Provider"].ToString();
    string email = cookie1["Email"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I added this to original post.

Comment: @FrenkyB now alsow its giving null?

Comment: Yes, if I try cookie["Provider"] it's null... really strange. Not logical.

Comment: this throws me an error, because value is null. I can't convert null to string.